# Joining two Postgres Database tables using Node.js query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure

I keep getting an iisnode encountered an error when trying to add a JOIN statement to the query statement below, removing "JOIN table_name2" then the query works. How can I fix the statement to get it to work? Any suggestions?

```
const getUserById = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)

  pool.query('SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 WHERE "GTIN" = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}
```

Table 1

```
      GTIN     |      gtinName  
--------+----------------+---------
26001087006846 |    Product Name
```

Table 2

```
      GTIN      |    nutrientTypeCode  
--------+-------------------+------------
 26001087006846 |        Protein
--------+-------------------+------------
 26001087006846 |         Energy
```

Desired Result

```
      GTIN     |    gtinName      |    nutrientTypeCode
--------+---------------+---------------------+------------
26001087006846 |   Product Name   |         FASAT
```

Comment: Update your question  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I have updated :)

Comment: I have posted  a brief answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a JOIN and the related on clause for JOIN  the two table

```
    const getUserById = (request, response) => {
      const id = parseInt(request.params.id)

      pool.query('SELECT table_1.GTIN, table_1.gtinNAme, table_2.nutrientTypeCode 
                   FROM table_1 
                   JOIN table_2 ON table_1.GTIN =  table_2.GTIN
                   NWHERE table_1.GTIN = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error
        }
        response.status(200).json(results.rows)
      })
    }
```

Comment: @ThomasK  .  exaplain better .. anyway i have updated the asnwer  there is a wrong GTI instead of GTIN

Comment: thanks, here is the error in the logs: error: column reference "GTIN" is ambiguous